# Migrar una web a otro alojamiento distinto de Google

Tags: web

¿Puedo migrar mi web de Google sites clásica a otro alojamiento distinto de Google o eso me supondría algún problema legar de derechos con Google?

Comment: Hola, no crees que es mejor preguntar eso en los foros de soporte de Google? Ahí si te darán una respuesta efectiva.